# listbox not showing error when empty

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

i am using listbox to get the input from user through textbox. if user gives input through textbox i can parse the value from listbox and do my operations.
now if user didnot give nay input, then listbox doesn't contain anything.
i want that if listbox is empty it should show error in msg box..
i am trying my code but it is not working..

```
string text1 = lstboxbulkto.ToString();
                if (lstboxbulkto.ToString().Equals(null))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("hiii");
                }
```

where lstboxbulkto is the name of the listbox.
how can this be done.

Comment: what is your platform? asp? silverlight? winforms? wpf? more info == better answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if a Listbox is empty, you can use the Listbox.Items.Count property. If the value is `0`, then the listbox is empty.

```
if(lstboxbulkto.Items.Count == 0)
   MessageBox.Show("hiii");
```